# Is there a convenient way to reach deeply related models data in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have these models:
`Channel` > `Program` > `Episode`

As you might guess, Channel has many programs, Program has many Episodes.

The thing is I want to reach `Episode` count of a given `Channel` type.

I can do it like this:

```
episodes = []
Channel.where(ctype: "4").each {|t| t.programs.each {|r| r.episodes.each {|m| episodes.push(m)}} }
episodes.size
```

But I don't think that this is the most convenient way.

Is there a better 'Rails way' to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Episodes are connected to Programs. Not Channels.

Comment: @SamD, that's not something possible. We're not talking about 'singular' connection. How can you make a has_many call to a plural ActiveRecord::Relation array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `has_many ... through` association for Episode, Program and Channel. And use `Channel.where(ctype: 4).episodes.count`

Or try to join the models

```
Episode.joins(:program => :channel).where('channels.ctype = ?', 4).count
```

Comment: This `where` clause can also be expressed as `channels: {ctype: 4}` if you prefer not to use raw sql statements. I think inverting the query like this is the best answer and an important technique to have available. When you want `Episode`s that's where you can start your query and restrict as needed. No need to add extra associations or run multiple queries.

Comment: Errr.. Sorry to be a noob but I got this error: `PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...s"."id" = "programs"."channel_id" WHERE (channels.ctype = 4)`

Comment: PG is strict on data type. Try to use string '4' instead of integer 4.

Comment: Your solution with 'joins' did work but I'm not clear how to make `has_many through` association work in this situation. Channel.where(ctype: "4") returns many objects. How can you use .episodes with it? And could you explain a little bit your 'joins' solution?

Comment: Well, @bbozo's answer is also correct. It needs `.joins(:episodes)` while using has_many through association.

Comment: Agree, it needs `.joins(:episodes)` for multiple Channel. Defining an association is useful when you need to have access to episodes somewhere else. For on-time query it's better to use plain query. `Episode.joins(:program => :channel)` you can treat it as "compose a virtual table from tables episodes, programs and channels; make an where query to it". Check this page to see how SQL join works http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 1):

Quick & dirty answer, will expand later today, but in broad terms, `has_many :through` relationship:

```
class Chanel
  has_many :programs
  has_many :episodes, through: :programs
end

class Program
  has_many :episodes
end

class Episode
end
```

and then a left outer join:

```
Channel.where(ctype: 4).joins(:episodes).count
```

should give you correct and optimal result